# regular expression to allow only 1 dash

Tags: java, regex

I have a textbox where I get the last name of a user. How do I allow only one dash (-) in a regular expression? And it's not supposed to be in the beginning or at the end of the string.
I have this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z-']", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
```

Comment: Is no dash an acceptable pattern? I would assume so, given that my last name does not contain a dash.

Comment: **That’s not a *dash***; it’s U+002D, the HYPHEN-MINUS character!  Don't forget
U+2010 HYPHEN, U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN, U+2012 FIGURE DASH, U+2013 EN
DASH, U+2014 EM DASH, U+2015 HORIZONTAL BAR, U+2053 SWUNG DASH, U+207B
SUPERSCRIPT MINUS, U+208B SUBSCRIPT MINUS, U+2212 MINUS SIGN, U+2E3A TWO-EM
DASH, and U+2E3B THREE-EM DASH — just to name a few.  There are more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your regex represents a fragment of an *invalid* value, and you're presumably using `Matcher.find()` to find if *any* part of your value matches that regex. Is that correct? If so, you can change your pattern to:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z'-]|-.*-|^-|-$");
```

which will match a non-letter-non-hyphen-non-apostrophe character, *or* a sequence of characters that both starts and ends with hyphens (thereby detecting a value that contains two hyphens), *or* a leading hyphen, *or* a trailing hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rephrase the question in more regexy terms. Rather than "allow only one dash, and it can't be at the beginning" you could say, "the string's beginning, followed by at least one non-dash, followed by one dash, followed by at least one non-dash, followed by the string's end."

- the string's beginning: `^
- at least one non-dash: `[^-]+`
- followed by one dash: `-`
- followed by at least one non-dash: `[^-]+`
- followed by the string's end: `$`

Put those all together, and there you go. If you're using this in a context that matches against the complete string (not just any substring within it), you don't need the anchors -- though it may be good to put them in anyway, in case you later use that regex in a substring-matching context and forget to add them back in.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; OP explicitly states that the dash cannot be at the end of the string.

Comment: You have shown me the secret to working out how to convert string queries into regex. *worships*

Comment: @diev Sorry, misread -- I thought it was only that it couldn't be at the beginning. Will edit. Perry Monschau, happy to help! :)

Comment: @PerryMonschau It would, but that also satisfies the OP's requirement that the hyphen isn't at the start or end of the string. If the OP wanted to tighten the requirements further, it wouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `indexOf()` in `String`?

```
String s = "last-name";
int first = s.indexOf('-');
int last = s.lastIndexOf('-');

if(first == 0 || last == s.length()-1) // Checks if a dash is at the beginning or end
    System.out.println("BAD");
if(first != last) // Checks if there is more than one dash
    System.out.println("BAD");
```

It is slower than using regex but with usually small size of last names it should not be noticeable in the least bit. Also, it will make debugging and future maintenance MUCH easier.

Comment: Because regex is by far more efficient.

Comment: @PerryMonschau While that may be true, in this case the strings are likely to be quite short, so performance gains, if any, would be minimal. As well, this code is *way* clearer about what the requirements are than a regex would be (as illustrated by the numerous (and sometimes wrong) regex answers already put forth.)

Answer (score 0):

This regex represents one or more *non-hyphens*, followed by a single hyphen, followed by one or more *non-hyphens*.

```
^[^\-]+\-[^\-]+$
```

I'm not sure if the hyphen in the middle needs to be escaped with a backslash... That probably depends on what platform you're using for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern something like [a-z]*-[a-z]*.

> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*-[a-z]*");